# How to jump between two UIViewcontrollers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I want to jump between two `UIViewcontrollers`

through swipe action.

Currently, I implemented a `UIScrollView`, and added `UIViewcontrollers`(vc1 and vc2) on it, so

On vc1

> swipe left : jump to vc2
>
> swipe right : do nothing

On vc2

> swipe left : do nothing
>
> swipe right : jump to vc1

But what I want is:

On vc1

> swipe left : jump to vc2
>
> swipe right : jump to vc2

On vc2

> swipe left : jump to vc1
>
> swipe right : jump to vc1

So, how to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Steps:

1. In your view controller Create a `UIPageViewController`

`self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];`

2. Add your both view controller on `UIPageViewController`

`NSArray *viewControllers = //add your two view controllers in array;`

`[self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];`

3. Set data source and Add `UIPageViewController` as child view controller

`self.pageController.dataSource = self;`
`[self addChildViewController:self.pageController];`

Now, You need to implement two methods

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSUInteger index = [(ViewController *)viewController index];

    if (index == 0) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Decrease the index by 1 to return
    index--;

    return viewControllers[index];//[self viewControllerAtIndex:index];//viewControllerAtIndex

}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSUInteger index = [(ViewController *)viewController index];

    if (index == 1) {
        return nil;
    }
    index++;

    return viewControllers[index];

}
```

Comment: There are some bugs in your code, but good to know that I should use UIPageViewController here.